# Fill DataTable using array of NewRows

Tags: c#, arrays, reporting-services, datatable

and thanks for the help! I'm trying to fill a DataTable before its pulled in a Report from Microsoft Reporting Services.

I originally thought I could run a for look (depending on how many rows there are in my "MainTable", and assign each category and flush it into a Rows.Add and repeat but apparently I cannot Row.Add the same name NewRow. Here's what I have thus far. thanks for the help!:

```
MyDataSet.ESSRow newESS = MyDataSet.ESS.NewESSRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["MainTable"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dRow = ds.Tables["MainTable"].Rows[i];
            if(Convert.ToInt32(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString()) > ShiftDelta)//checks if instance is longer than a shift 
            {
            newESS.Station = "7";
            newESS.Switch ="7";
            newESS.Start = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
            newESS.Stop = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
            newESS.SwitchIs = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(8).ToString();
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString()));
            newESS.Duration = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s", t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
            MyDataSet.ESS.Rows.Add(newESS);                 }

        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't try to add the same row several times, instead create a new row to add in each iteration of the loop.  This can be done most simply by just moving the declaration of `newESS` to be *inside* of the loop rather than *outside* of the loop.  Beyond that, you should also move it to be inside of the `if` statement so that you aren't creating a new row if you aren't going to add one.

Comment: Let me give this a try, and I will respond shortly!

Answer (score 0):

Also try to rather use importRow as this does not give the annoying row already belongs to another table error.